# How to combine two queries in Rails using OR support

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'd like to join two queries using Active Record's "OR":

```
@category_ids = [4,5,6,7]
@sub_category_ids = [1,3,5,6]

@products1 = @products.joins(:inventory_categorizations).distinct.where(inventory_categorizations: {inventory_category_id: @sub_category_ids, inventory_category_type: "SubCategory"})

@products2 = @products.joins(:inventory_categorizations).distinct.where(inventory_categorizations: {inventory_category_id: @category_ids, inventory_category_type: "Category"})

@products = @products1 | @products2
```

Is there anyway that I can use this?

```
@products = @products.joins(:inventory_categorizations).distinct.where(inventory_categorizations: {inventory_category_id: @sub_category_ids, inventory_category_type: "SubCategory" or inventory_category_id: @category_ids, inventory_category_type: "Category"})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like -

```
@products.joins(:inventory_categorizations)
         .distinct
         .where(inventory_categorizations: {inventory_category_id: @sub_category_ids, inventory_category_type: "SubCategory"})
         .or(
           @products.joins(:inventory_categorizations)
           .distinct
           .where(inventory_categorizations: {inventory_category_id: @category_ids, inventory_category_type: "Category"})
         )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that goal in two different ways;

1. Writing the where clause on your own:

   ```rb
   where_clause = <<~SQL
     (
       inventory_categorizations.inventory_category_id = ?
       AND 
       inventory_categorizations.inventory_category_type = ?
     )
     OR 
     (
       inventory_categorizations.inventory_category_id = ?
       AND
       inventory_categorizations.inventory_category_type = ?
     )
   SQL

   @products.joins(:inventory_categorizations)
           .where(where_clause, @sub_category_ids, "SubCategory", @category_ids, "Category")
           .distinct
   ```
2. Using Active Record's `QueryMethods#or` method if you are using Rails version 5 or above.  All you need to do is use `or` instead of the `|`(or) operator:

   ```rb
   @products = @products1.or(@products2)
   ```

Comment: It doesn't work at all.  I can get the duplicated results.

Comment: which one did you try? First approach or the second one? Also what is your `@ products` query?